# How do I copy a node(object) in Firebase to another node?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a node called Events in Firebase. It consists of child objects like: `address`, `description`, `longitude`, `latitude`. Before a user deletes an event node I want to copy it to the same database to a node called `eventsDeleted`.

This is the code for deleting the node:

```
removeEvent(eventId, groupId) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {

    this.eventRef.child(groupId).child(eventId).remove();
    resolve();

  });

}
```

This is the code for creating the node:

```
addEvent(data:any) {
    console.log('Form data', data.group);

    let localEventRef = firebase.database().ref('events').child(data.group.split(',')[1]);
    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    let file = data.image;
    let uploadTask = storageRef.child('eventImages/' + UuidGenerator.generateUUID()).put(file);
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', function (snapshot) {

    }, function (error) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        console.error(error);
    }, function () {
        // Handle successful uploads on complete
        let downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
        let keyOfNewEvent = localEventRef.push(
            new Event(
                null,
                firebase.app().auth().currentUser.uid,

                data.description,


                data.location.address,
                0

            )
        ).key;
        localEventRef.child(keyOfNewEvent).update({eventId: keyOfNewEvent});
    });


}
```

Never mind the code for uploading an image. I just need a way to copy that entire node if possible then paste it somewhere in the database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use [angular.copy()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) and create a new item with it

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks delete, make sure to get the object that's being deleted, if you were to query your database for that object you can use the `.once` to retrieve the object otherwise you can just jump to the `removeEvent` function directly.

```
localEventRef.child(keyOfEvent).once("value", function(snapshot) {
 //one data is returned, you can then call the removeEvent fn

  let eventToBeRemoved = snapshot.val();
  //assuming you have the eventid, groupid then. 
  removeEvent(eventId, groupId, eventToBeRemoved);
});

removeEvent(eventId, groupId, eventObjectToBeRemoved) {
//firebase 3.x comes with a promise method

    firebase.database().ref('eventsDeleted/' + groupId + '/' + eventId )
      .set({...eventObjectToBeRemoved})
      .then(function () { 
        eventRef.child(groupId).child(eventId).remove();//you can now remove
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("error occured trying to add to deletedEvents", error);
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: I am not able to execute this code as it is, i'm sorry. i was able to put the first three lines of your code into the removeEvent() function. I ran that an i was able to delete the event as before but It did not create a node on the database called "eventsDeleted" with the data as I had hoped. I'm almost there, just missing something. Can you assist further thanks.

Comment: oh i hope you didn't add these `.....eventObjectToBeRemoved` on the `.set` as it was just an example? it's meant to be an object like `{event: "", id: ""}`...

Comment: Thanks alot for your replies. Could I use eventRef.child(groupId).child(eventId) inside the set()? or does it have to be the  {event: "", id: ""} ?

Comment: or put eventToBeRemoved inside set?

Comment: eventToBeRemoved  inside set @kuhle